# Select the last date from multiple rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

So i have a small issue:
I have users who can enter a test multiple times. I want to inner join the users table with the results of the last test they took.

TABLES: USERS, TESTRESULTS

I'm kinda stuck on the syntax, got it like this right now

```
SELECT USERS.*, TESTRESULTS.result
FROM USERS
INNER JOIN TESTRESULTS
ON USERS.id = TESTRESULTS.user_id
WHERE TESTRESULTS.date IN (SELECT id, MAX(date) FROM TESTRESULTS GROUP BY id)
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
user_id, (latest result for test)
1, 98
2, 77
3, 100
```

The users can take as many tests as they like, but only the last one will count.

Help would be really appreciated :)

EDIT 2: The used query returns an SQL error.

```
CREATE TABLE passie_users AS
    SELECT users.*, assesspassionresults.score_data, assesspassionresults.score_ideas, assesspassionresults.score_people, assesspassionresults.score_things,
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN assesspassionresults
        ON users.id = assesspassionresults.user_id
    WHERE assesspassionresults.status = 'active'
    AND (users.id, assesspassionresults.modified) IN (SELECT id, max(modified) FROM assesspassionresults);
```

Comment: Please post the table structure of the tables.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a little something in the `IN()` statement :

```
SELECT USERS.*, TESTRESULTS.result
FROM USERS
INNER JOIN TESTRESULTS
ON USERS.id = TESTRESULTS.user_id
WHERE (users.id,TESTRESULTS.date) IN (SELECT user_id, MAX(date) FROM TESTRESULTS GROUP BY user_id)
```

You have to compare the same number of arguments and the same type when using `IN()` .

Comment: Can you explain what you did with the WHERE statement? It looks like the correct answer indeed

Comment: Like I said, when using `IN()` the same amount+type of arguments should be placed in both the sides of the `IN()`  E.G. -> `WHERE (ID,NAME,AGE) IN(SELECT ID,NAME,AGE FROM..` is a correct one, and `WHERE (ID,NAME,AGE) IN(SELECT ID,NAME FROM...)` is a wrong one.

Comment: Ah it all makes sense now! Thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: I've a small problem though. It returns me a code 1064 when I try this solution. Check my query, if you'd like :)

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM users     INNER JOIN assesspassionresults   ON users.id = assesspassionresu' at line 3

Comment: I'm so sorry for wasting your time @sagi . I found the culprit, it was a comma hidden behind the last select statement. Again thanks a lot for your time and effort!

Comment: No problem mate, I have a feeling the inner query should be with `userid` and not `id` , check that . @Adam

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out, I was indeed getting 0 rows returned. That fixed it aswell haha!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: not the correct answer, my apologies!

```
SELECT USERS.*, TESTRESULTS.result, max(TESTRESULTS.date)
FROM USERS
   INNER JOIN TESTRESULTS
       ON USERS.id = TESTRESULTS.user_id
GROUP BY TESTRESULTS.date;
```

Comment: That's not entirely correct, this will only give you the maximum date, not the corresponding record to it.

Comment: This is definitely NOT the answer to anything!